# Android app (embedded WebView) crashes when forcing landscape orientation

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, html5-canvas, android-webview

I have an HTML5 app, almost all of which takes place in Canvas. In the JS, I've set exact dimensions for the height and width of the canvas. I've also used a lot of absolute positioning with magic numbers to make the layout perfect. Note: everything is designed around landscape orientation and portrait isn't an option.

Running this in modern versions of Chrome, everything works great - Chrome seems to scale the canvas properly when the page loads (regardless of viewport size), and the absolutely positioned canvas drawing / HTML elements' positions scale accordingly.

But now I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with an Android app - very simple app that just loads a *WebView*, without anything containing it. The canvas is much smaller than the phone's resolution, so I'd imagine this should work.

**My specific problem is that setting *android:screenOrientation="landscape"* in the Manifest file always makes the app crash immediately. My guess is that it's interacting badly with my main layout file, but I can't figure out how.** I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S6, and building the app to SDK version 21.

What I want is behavior like I get in a desktop Chrome browser, but I can't seem to find a way that either fails to display the entire HTML5 Canvas, or crashes the app immediately.

Here is the JS I am using to position the canvas, which (in desktop Chrome) works - note that *canvas#board* is the canvas element.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

// some irrelevant code omitted...

var XRES  = 640;
var YRES  = 280;
var X_OFF = (window.innerWidth  - XRES) / 2;
var Y_OFF = (window.innerHeight - YRES) / 2;

// some irrelevant code omitted...

$('#board').css('left', X_OFF);
$('#board').css('top',  Y_OFF);
$('#submitDialog').css('left', X_OFF + 222);
$('#submitDialog').css('top',  Y_OFF +  41);
```

This centers the canvas in both dimensions regardless of the full viewport size, and centers the *submitDialog* (a *div* that is eventually used to submit high scores).

What I would like is a way to change either the HTML/JS, or the Android project configuration to achieve the same thing. The ideal is that I could make the WebView automatically scale to say 90% of the screen size. Any thoughts? My thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was never able to make it work via the Manifest **orientation=landscape** property, but using *setRequestedOrientation()* in *onCreate()* works perfectly. I also had to set the *WebView* dimensions to the exact size the JS sets the Canvas element.

There were a few problems with scale and offset, easily solved by adjusting the scale and margin properties of the *WebView* (again with magic numbers, but I am sure the right values for any device could be computed and set in *onCreate()*.